# Are there any peer-to-peer web conferencing API's for .NET?

Tags: .net, webcam

I'm wondering if anyone has experience building an application like Skype (peer-to-peer), and what technologies and software packages you leveraged?  I haven't been able to find a .Net API to build a web conferencing application, but I guess I'm open to any platform.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a bunch of APIs out there for different component aspects of web conferencing, but there's no single API that I know of that will cover all your bases for you. For instance, to handle the webcam portion of things using DirectShow.NET ([Tutorial and download](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/WebcamUsingDirectShowNET.aspx)). For the peer-to-peer chat/IM aspect of things you can check out [this WPF/WCF application](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WCF/WPFWCF_Chat_App_via_P2P.aspx)

I hope that helps you to get started.

Comment: Neat, I'm mainly looking for audio & video in a single package.

Comment: Well, if you are familiar at all with Silverlight 4 there are APIs for both webcam and audio access built-in.

Comment: Have silverlight got microphone support? It hadn't last time I checked

Comment: @jgauffin Yes, but only in Silverlight 4, not in previous versions. There's a quick overview on Tim Heuer's blog: http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2009/11/18/whats-new-in-silverlight-4-complete-guide-new-features.aspx#webcam